# Running JQuery within PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a PHP file that output some information within a JQuery TAB.

PHP file

```
$output2 .='<div class="demo">';
$output2 .='<div id="tabs">';
$output2 .='<ul>';
$output2 .='<li><a href="#tabs-1">Option 1</a></li>';
$output2 .='<li><a href="#tabs-2">Option 2</a></li>';
$output2 .='</ul>';
$output2 .='<div id="tabs-1">';
$output2 .='<p>1st text.</p>';
$output2 .='</div>';
$output2 .='<div id="tabs-2">';
$output2 .='<p>2nd text.</p>';
$output2 .='</div>';
$output2 .='</div>';
$output2 .='</div>';
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demos.css">    
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<?php echo $output2; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the php everything works less the jquery function. If I run the script directly within a HTML file, runs perfectly

Comment: Please view the source of the page in the browser, and paste it here. Even better, create a JSFiddle with it. The PHP doesn't matter, the compiled HTML does.

Comment: How is the PHP related to the HTML? is there some templating system you're not mentioning?

Comment: is path to scripts the same when run in php file as in html file? What errors are being thrown in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

The following script

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

finds and applies the final output of the tabs into the document, however, you're calling this function before the php output actually "outputting", therefore all jquery events are not applied, you can fix this just by putting the "tabs" function after that echo.

Answer (score -3):

I think that this will solve it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();        
    });    
});
```

and for faster page load - put it at the bottom.

Comment: The proper way to post code, with syntax highlighting, is to indent it with four spaces.  Not use back-ticks.

Comment: `$(function() {...})` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {...})`. Your answer will do nothing except add further redundancy.

Comment: `$(function() {})` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(...)`, they do the same thing, double-stacking would stop the code from ever being run, because the document only becomes ready once.